# How build a flutter app for each export method for iOS with fastlane

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, fastlane, flutter-ios

I need to deploy my app ad-hoc and to the play store, currently in my CI flow I do this for every PR with Fastlane:

```rb
sh("flutter build ios")
build_app(export_method: method)
```

- [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/): tool to automate the build/test/deploy steps.
- [build_app](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_app/): is a plugin from fastlane to build iOS, and I use it because I can declare if the build is `ad-hoc` or `app-store`.

I was worried that I'm doing 2 times the same thing, first time I build with flutter and then with native XCode.

I have two questions:

1. Can I build the flutter iOS build for each method from a flutter command?
2. What is the difference of build the iOS from flutter instead of running it from XCode like a total native iOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `update_code_signing_settings` with profile name for each export method so the build configure itself with the profile:

```rb
# method could be 'ad-hoc' or app-store

update_code_signing_settings(profile_name: "My export method profile")
build_app(export_method: method)
```